# Issue while getting start and end date of current Year

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I searched a lot on Google to get the start and end date of the current year.
Now, After 2 hours of search, posted the query here.

Below is what i have tried so far. but not working.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$startDate = new \DateTime($date);
$endDate = new \DateTime($date);
$endDate->modify("+1 day -1 second");
```

can you please guide me in right direction ?

Comment: the start and end date of this year is date("Y-01-01") and date("Y-12-31") respectively

Comment: get the start and end date of the current year => You mean the week day?

Comment: Are you looking for a Unix timestamp?  strtotime("January 1st 0:00");  strtotime("December 31st 23:59");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the start date: `date('Y-01-01')` and end date `date('Y-12-31')`.

If you use Carbon, to get the weekdays:

```
$year = date('Y');
$date = Carbon::create($year, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0);
$date->toDateTimeString($year, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0);  // 2016-12-31 00:00:00
$date->format('l'); // Saturday

$date2 = Carbon::create($year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
$date2->toDateTimeString($year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);  // 2016-01-01 00:00:00
$date2->format('l'); // Firday
```